# Unexpected token import using node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple file **numeral.js** that I'm trying to test with mocha running through node.

An afternoon of searching however has left me at the first hurdle.

Numeral.js:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.numeral = function (id) {
    return "";
};
```

test.js

```
import {numeral} from './numeral.js'

var assert = require('assert');

describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
    });
  });

});
```

I navigate to the folder (that has mocha set up as test in the packages.json) and run **npm test**.  That throws out a:

```
C:\Users\matt\Documents\mocha\test\test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {numeral} from './numeral.js'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

How am I going so wrong?

Comment: Your error is starrring on you already. Import keyword is not available yet on any node version. You need babel preset for that

Comment: try to require it mate

Comment: Node does not support ES6 imports, it uses the `commonjs` module syntax, so use `require` instead of `import`.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Sometimes people downvote because it makes them feel good inside. I have this same question, but I am registering Babel so, I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs  does not support import and export.

So, you have to use babel to covert your es6 code to es5 version if you like to use import/export. take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53) in github